# Drawing on top of a QGraphicsItem with higher zValue

Tags: python, graph, qt5, qgraphicsitem, pyqt5

I have some elements arranged into a `QGraphicsScene` (nodes and edges inheriting `QGraphicsItem`). Nodes can be connected to many other nodes using edges (sounds obvious but better to point it out). In my code, whenever I add a new edge between 2 nodes, I make sure that the `zValue` of the edge is lower than the `zValue` of the connected nodes (the anchor point of an edge is by default the center of the node). Now I encountered the need of moving the anchor point of each edge within the node: to do that I would need to draw a handle which can be used to interactively move the anchor point: something like this:

[image]

Here comes the problem. Since the edge `zValue` is lower than the ones of the nodes, some parts of the edges are obscured by the shape of the nodes (as supposed to). Now I would need to draw the handle on top of the node. I already tried to draw the handle from within the node shape `paint` method but then I cannot interact with it (it would be just some useless drawing): what I need is to draw an handle which will be visible and with which I can interact (using `mouseMoveEvent` for example).

How can I achieve this behavior?

I tried to implement this in another way: drawing edges on top of nodes and dynamically adjust the intersection point with the source and target node (not to draw the overlapping part of the edge) but this is introducing a lot of artifacts when moving nodes around (probably because it takes too much time to compute the intersection so everything slows down). I'm not posting the code of this implementation (yet) since I would like to solve the problem in some other way, but I have no problem in doing that if this is the only way to achieve what I need.

I'm using PyQt5 and Python 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the handles independent QGraphicsItems with a higher Z but "linked" to the edge that they are attached to.  You can't link them by making them children of the edge (because then their Z values would no longer apply - they would be overridden by the edge). I'm not sure if you could group them in a QGraphicsItemGroup but I suspect that won't work either.  But you can just manage the grouping yourself with pointers in the handles and edges.

Then when the user moves the handle you can move the edge yourself.

Comment: In the end I decided to go for the solution 2, so drawing edges on top of nodes, removing the portion of the edge being draw on top of source/target nodes (so basically now the edge is attached to the intersection point). I managed to speed up the algorithm I created before so now it shows less artifacts.